# Taking first observation of a series as unobserved parameter in non-linear regression

Tags: stata, non-linear-regression

I am trying to estimate the following equation in Stata using non-linear least squares command `nl`:
π_t= π_t_e+ α (y-y*)
where π_t_e= γ * π_t-1_e+(1-γ) π_(t-1)

π_t, y and y* are already given in the dataset, π_t_e is created from π_t using second equation. There are 34 observations in the dataset. The first observation of π_t_e i.e. π_1_e is treated as an unobserved parameter, along with gamma and alpha.

I wrote the following code but it is not working:

```
local s "{pi_1_e}"
local s "({gamma}*L.`s'+ (1-{gamma})*L.pi)"
nl ( pi = (`s') + {alpha}*(y-y*))
```

The first line of the code assigns `pi_1_e` to `s`. But the second line replaces `s` with

```
 ({gamma}*L.`s'+ (1-{gamma})*L.pi)
```

For `_n==1`, `L.s` doesn't exist. Hence, it is replaced with a missing value and all other 33 observations are assigned missing values. I wish to run second line of the code from `_n>=2`. But `if` condition doesn't work with local macro.

Can someone help me understand how to resolve this?

Comment: I don't fully understand this, but `nl` can't work with linked equations, and lag operators can't be applied to parameters, only to variables.   Using local macros can't solve this, as the most they can do here is string manipulation to ease coding. In comparison the previous value not being defined in the first observation doesn't look like an issue. `nl` should just ignore observations with missing values.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your reply. pi_t_e is an independent variable, where subsequent observations in the series depend on lagged observations of itself and of pi_t, which is the dependent variable. Since pi_t_e depends on lagged values of itself, I need to provide an initial value to be able to calculate the rest of the series. I am treating that initial value as an unobserved parameter, and then trying to run non-linear regression using nl, but my code is not working properly. Any suggestion on how to accomplish that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: From `nl`'s narrow point of view, I don't think that makes any sense. `nl` has no sense of a parameter as anything but a single constant to be estimated. I don't have experience with this model to suggest other Stata code. I'd ask on Statalist.

Comment: Okay sure, thank you so much.